# No mailbox was found that includes the external directory object ID that was specified when using direct authorization

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

When I access the Graph API using Graph Explorer logged on with my work account the following REST call works without any problems

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups('42bc2ab5-230f-475c-8663-7c319d0b6696')/conversations?expand=threads(expand=posts)
```

The GUID is the ID of the Office 365 Group

When I try accessing using direct authorisation of which I used the following guide to configure for my Windows Console app

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds/

The following 404 error is returned with the following JSON response.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorNonExistentMailbox",
    "message": "No mailbox was found that includes the external directory object ID that was specified.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "e8a5f034-3e8c-496c-896e-250acea6fe1c",
      "date": "2016-10-26T10:16:27"
    }
  }
}
```

If I access the group directly using the following REST call it works OK

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups('42bc2ab5-230f-475c-8663-7c319d0b6696')
```

But when I try to access the conversations the error above is returned.

My app is configured with the following permissions using https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

**Delegated Permissions**

Mail.Read, Mail.Read.Shared, User.Read, Group.Read.All (Admin Only), Group.ReadWrite.All (Admin Only)

**Application Permissions**

Group.Read.All (Admin Only), Group.ReadWrite.All (Admin Only), Mail.Read (Admin Only), User.Read.All (Admin Only)

This the code I'm using in my Console app

```
class Program
    {
        private const string AUTHORITY_FORMAT = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0";
        private const string GRAPH_SCOPE = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
        private const string GROUP_ATTACHMENTS_GRAPH_QUERY = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups('42bc2ab5-230f-475c-8663-7c319d0b6696')/conversations?expand=threads(expand=posts)";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ScanGroupConversations().Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }

        static async Task ScanGroupConversations()
        {
            // Get a token for the Microsoft Graph
            ConfidentialClientApplication daemonClient =
                new ConfidentialClientApplication(
                    String.Format(AUTHORITY_FORMAT, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tennantId"]),
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redirectUri"],
                    new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"]), new TokenCache());

            AuthenticationResult authResult = await daemonClient.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { GRAPH_SCOPE }, null);

            // Query for list of users in the tenant
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, GROUP_ATTACHMENTS_GRAPH_QUERY);

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.Token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode + "Content: " + responseString);
                //throw new HttpResponseException(response.StatusCode);
            }

            // Record users in the data store (note that this only records the first page of users)
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need any delegated permissions when you are using the app-only confidential client flow, but equally they should not be making any difference.   The Graph explorer is using delegated flows with delegated permissions to read the conversations.   I've sent a request to the conversations team to see if they support app-only confidential client flows yet.

Comment: Thank you @garethj should have explained that the delegated permissions is for some other functionality of the App.

Comment: They do not yet support app-only conversation flows.

Comment: Is this on the future roadmap? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but no ETA at present.